# Move inner array values to parent array, reset keys and change key name to string

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array as such:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 30
        [2] => 33
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
    )
```

I want to move all values in the `[0]` index out so they become part of the parent array. So the final outcome would look like such:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [id] => 1
)

[1] => Array
(
    [id] => 30
)

[2] => Array
(
    [id] => 33
)

[3] => Array
(
    [id] => 5
)
```

As you can see the numerical indexes on `[0]` have now changed to `id`
I've tried using `array_map('current', $array[0])`
to no avail, any suggestions?

Comment: Why have the indexes changed specifically to "id"? What's the algorithm that decides that in the general case?

Comment: Its for a navigation bar feature we use that requires it to be 'id'

Comment: I 'm not asking *why*, but *how*. A good answer will include code. Do you want that code to have a hardcoded `"id"` inside? If not, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Where the hell that id 32 came from in the second code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$data = array(
    array(1, 30, 33),
    array('id' => 5)
);

$result = array();
array_walk_recursive(
    $data,
    function($value) use (&$result) {
        $result[] = array('id' => $value);
    }
);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I'd have expected something involving `Iterator`s from you... ;)

Comment: @deceze - I do enjoy using my callbacks as well

Comment: @deceze - Answer using iterators duly provided :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the ol' trusty double `foreach`:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($array as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $ar) {
        $new_array[] = array('id'=>$ar);
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/w9JpqpNU)

Answer (score 1):

Just to show that iterators can be really useful tools as well:

```
$data = array(
    array(1, 30, 33),
    array('id' => 5)
);

$result = array();
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
             new RecursiveArrayIterator($data),
             RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
         ) as $value) {
    $result[] = array('id' => $value);
}
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
    [1, 30, 33],
    ['id' => 5]
];

$result = array_reduce($array, function (array $result, array $array) {
    return array_merge($result, array_map(
        function ($id) { return compact('id'); },
        array_values($array)
    ));
}, []);

var_dump($result);
```

Admittedly not the simplest way to solve this, but very "functional". ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    array(0 => 1,1 => 30,2 => 33,),
    array("id" => 5,)
);

$result = array_merge(
    array_map('array_flip', 
        array_chunk(
            array_fill_keys($array[0], "id"),
            1, true)
        ), 
    array_slice($array, 1)
);

var_export($result);
```

Results in:

```
array ( 
    array ( 'id' => 1 ), 
    array ( 'id' => 30 ), 
    array ( 'id' => 33 ), 
    array ( 'id' => 5 ) 
)
```